# Tool to compare designs

Tags: color, fonts, tools, template

I am looking for a tool (not Software / Programm) to compare corporate designs consisting of colors, fonts, logo and lines etc. I have something in mind  like a onepager / card / palette with a selection of fonts/text, colors and other visual elements etc.

There are examples for colors like http://Paletton.com or http://designmodo.com/identifying-fonts-creating-palette/ for fonts.

I want a simple to use palette that includes everything to compare myself and show the customer.

I think this is a common Task, so I thought there might be experiences here how to create such a thing.

Any Tips or pointers?

I am no professional, rather a motivated Amateur so any Support is appreciate.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to explain better, I don't understand your question. A few screenshots might help. What kind of designs are you talking about, for example? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Vincent! I tried to rephrase. Does that make sense to you now?

Comment: Not clear yet. What do you mean by "compare corporate designs"? What do you want to show to your customer? What do you mean by "Tool" if it's not a software (you mean an online tool?)?

Comment: perhaps it makes sense to others ... btw, the tone here is a bit irritating ...

Comment: I had no intention of sounding irritated, if I came across as that, I apologise :). I was honestly really puzzled by what you meant.

Comment: Are you trying to find an online tool to do this comparison or are you trying to build a tool to do this comparison?

Comment: We're just trying to fish for more info to make the question easier to understand and get better answers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy way to compare all aspects of corporate designs of multiple companies in one place. (If I understood your question correctly).

I suggest you use [Trello](https://trello.com/). This is a free online tool, really simple to use. It consists of cards arranged in tables (you define number of tables and cards on each one, as well as their order) where you can upload all the design aspects you wish to show to your client.

I also suggest you use the palletes and comparison software yourself not to confuse your customer. You should show only the end-result to avoid confusion.